# How to seperate page for printing when users click on the check box by using CSS

Tags: html, css, printing

i've already follwed this http://davidwalsh.name/css-page-breaks and it works!!

but i want to add an additional function which it will be seperated to the new page only if the user check on the check box.

Here is CSS code

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked  {         
      @media print {
        .page-break { display: block; page-break-before: always; }
            }            
}
```

and this is my checkbox code

```
<input type="checkbox"> Check me
```

Thanks !!

Comment: I don't think it works that way. You can't add `@media` inside a normal rule.

Comment: yeah.. i know it doesnt work but just trying

Comment: I donkt think you can do it with CSS alone.

Answer (score 1):

can't be done just with CSS, You have to go with some Java-script.
Togle class